# The practical (Halachic) importance of the Luchot Habrit (the Tablets)

Tags: halacha-theory, aseres-hadibros

Is there any practical נ"מ (implications) **of the fact** that the 10 Mitzvos are written in the Luchos, and not in the plain text of the Torah outside the Luchos?

For example:

- because "לא תרצח" is written in the Luchos it is something, and it wouldn't be so if otherwise.
- Honoring one's parents IS written in the Luchos but Fearing them the is not in the Luchos - what's the practical difference?
- How "Thou shalt not covet" is different from the Isur of revenge, because it is written in the Luchos?

Comment: " and not in the plain text of the Torah" - WHAT??? It's in my version of the Torah. I don't know which version you've been viewing? Do you have a copy of the luchot in your home? Which one - the 1st or the second? Oh, I forgot - the 1st one is broken.

Comment: @DanF Ha ha ha, but I edited it.

Comment: That's what minim say...see Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 1:5 and Ba'er Heitev 11 there.

Comment: @chachamNisan I don't understand what you say about minim - do they say ha ha ha? Don't spare words, please.

Comment: There is no halachic priority given to the Ten Commandments over any of the other 603 mitzvot...only the minim say so by mistakenly believing that since only the Ten Commandments were written on the luchot, then only they are from HaShem.

Comment: @chachamNisan A good point, but that was only a regulation by the Chachamim (I remember the Gemorah in Berochos), TO PREVENT minim from saying the 10 commandments in Krishm"A, when in fact there IS some difference, we could say the 10C in Krishm"A to emphasize their importance.

Comment: You miss the point...and there is no difference. Only minim say that...

Comment: @chachamNisan OK then, so what do we say - why the Luchos at all? Why the 10C? Write the whole Torah on the tablets.